# Using SQL to search a column for keywords from another table and tag the column with an attribute

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

basically I have a table of keywords and posts I want tagged with attributes on the display.  like I want to draw a green border if #green# is present in the post.  Is there a clean way for the DB to do this internally?  I am prepared to do it all in C++ by fetching the entire table of keywords and throwing it in a trie and scanning each word, but this approach seems a bit inelegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing storage and display concerns. There be dragons. You are looking for `content like '%#green#%'`. It would be better to set a bit column or some other flag as the content was inserted or updated from the application side. When reading, retrieve this information along with the content. Let your display logic do the colouring.

Take a look at "separation of concerns" (SoC) as part of the S.O.L.I.D. practices.

Hope this helps.